# GNOME terminal not opening in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python, gnome-terminal

I upgraded my python to 3.7.1 from 3.6 since then I am not able to open my GNOME terminal. I reinstalled gnome-terminal.
Using the command

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal && sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
```

But it is not opening. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> is also not working.

I opened Xterm and typed "gnome-terminal".

I got this error

```
Cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi'(/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

Screenshot of error:

[image: Screenshot]

Output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python3`:

```
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/python3': No such file or directory
```

I'm getting errors in `apt` commands also:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed. 
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. 
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
Setting up iotop (0.6-2) ... /var/lib/dpkg/info/iotop.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/iotop.postinst: py3compile: not found dpkg: error processing package iotop (--configure): installed iotop package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127 
Errors were encountered while processing: iotop 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/32640083/7911552

Comment: @TheOneAboveAll It is not working, xterm says "Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported" . I tried to change to python3 to python3.7,3.6,3.5 it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By updating alternatives, you've set Python 3 as default even when `python` is called. This may break some packages. So, it's better to use aliases as far as python is considered. Roll back the change you made:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

and choose python2. `python` is always used to call Python 2 and `python3` to call Python 3.

GNOME terminal depends on default version of Python 3 (here 3.6). In your installation GNOME terminal was trying to run with Python 2 which will obviously not satisfy its dependency. So, modify the very first line of `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` and change it to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Now, in your installation python3 wasn't in /usr/bin/ and py3compile wasn't found, they can be restored by reinstalling python3-minimal:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-minimal
```

Comment: Hey, I followed your guide and it didn't work until a few hours later I found another answer that had --reinstall python3-minimal in the command instead and that finally worked. Is that a typo in your answer?

Comment: @m3h0wn *Year and a half later:* Yes. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened because I made a symlink to point to python3.7 as default python3 version.

DO NOT do that.

It breaks gnome-terminal and may break other apps as well.

In my case to restore python3.6 as default python3 interpreter, I just re-created a symlink named python3 pointing to python3.6.

```
cd /usr/bin
ln -s python3.6 python3
```